# flash cs6 AS3 :Getting error when publish fla file in CS5 environment

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

When I publish a "fla" file in CS6 environment, got following error.

ComponentShim (Compiled Clip), Line 1   5000: The class 'fl.controls.Button' must subclass 'flash.display.SimpleButton' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
Please help with a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is ...

i forget to add this statement:
 import flash.filesystem.*;

^_^